# Prove that the ideal of $p\in \mathbb Z[x]$ with $p(1)$ even is not principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the set $I$ of polynomials $p(x)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $p(1)$ is even. Prove that this is a non-principal ideal.

That this is an ideal is clear. I was wondering whether my proof that $I$ is non-principal correct?

Assume $I=(f)$. Since $2\in I$, $2=f(x)g(x)$ for $f,g\in \mathbb Z[x]$, and this implies that $f$ must be constant. This constant can only be equal to $2$ because otherwise $2\notin I$. But on the other hand, $x^2+1\in I$, so $x^2+1=2g(x)$. This is impossible because the LHS is not divisible by $2$.

Comment: I would like to point out that $I=\langle 2,x-1\rangle$ (this is a maximal ideal!).  About your proof, it is correct, and quite nice, actually.

Comment: One small comment: There are actually four possibilities for the constant value of $f$, $2$, $1$, $-1$, and $-2$. Two of them ($1$ and $-1$) are clearly not in $I$, so they can be ruled out; $2$ and $-2$ are functionally the same. Still, you should probably *say* that. Otherwise, this proof looks good to me.

Comment: As an addition to Batominovski's comment, to see that $I\subseteq (2,x-1)$, use little Bézout's theorem: $p(x)=(x-1)q(x)+p(1)$. If $p(1)$ is even, then $p(x)$ is a linear combination of $x-1$ and $2$. The other inclusion is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, apart from a very minor detail ($f(x)$ could also be $-2$, but then $2$ would be a generator as well).

A slightly different approach: the map $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}[x]$ defined by $\varphi\colon p(x)\mapsto p(x+1)$ is an isomorphism (with inverse $p(x)\mapsto p(x-1)$). Note that $\varphi(I)$ is the ideal consisting of the polynomials $p$ such that $p(0)$ is even.

It's quite clear that $\varphi(I)=(2,x)$, which is not principal, because a possible generator $f(x)$ must have even constant term, but then $x=f(x)g(x)$ is not possible, unless the constant term is $0$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove that $(2,x)$ is not principle by saying that $(2,x)$ is a $\mathbb Z[x]$-module of rank $2$, and if $(2,x)$ were a principle ideal, it would have rank 1 as a module?

Comment: @user538518 I'm not sure one can.